# Como salvar os resultados de um "drag-and-drop" em tabela?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drag-n-drop

Eu preciso fazer um drag-and-drop que se pareça como a imagem abaixo, que é o sistema que estou desenvolvendo.

Nos botões referentes a "1º Período", "2º Período" e demais, coloquei uma função que retorna as disciplinas referente ao período informado.

[Exemplo de table http://associacaoeua.com.br/particular/img/horario.png](http://associacaoeua.com.br/particular/img/horario.png)
codigo  =

```html
<td><type="button" onClick="disc('1');">1º Periodo</button></td>
```

---

Ativei o drag no retorno das disciplinas, portanto consigo arrastá-la até o dia e hora desejado com:

```
draggable="true" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"  ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

quando solto a disciplina em um determinado local consigo pegar o código (ID) dele
segue código que utilizei:

```js
function drag(ev) {
    revert:true,
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    //o id da disciplina esta na variavel data.
    alert(data);
   //data é o ID     
}
```

Eu consigo salvar no banco usando Ajax, o que não consigo é pegar o dia e a hora da aula. Apenas estou conseguindo pegar o ID da disciplina.

Assim que a disciplina for solta tenho que ter no

```js
function drop(ev) {

    *var id  : ja tenho.* 
    var dia : ex.. SEGUNDA.
    var hora: ex.. 6:10 a 7:40

}
```

Como eu devo fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é a sua pergunta? Favor editar sua pergunta, esclarecendo qual é seu problema específico (é fazer o drag and drop? é enviar os dados pro servidor? é salvar no BD?), o que você já fez até agora (com trechos de código de preferência), e o que está te causando dificuldade.

Comment: @user4870 Eu dei uma editada geral, por que não estava dando para entender. Se está errado, só edita aí...

Comment: Você quer mover as celulas ou a tabela? Mover pra onde?

Comment: Dei -1, sua pergunta está muito vaga e cheia de questionamentos. Não está clara.

Comment: Acho que esta pergunta poderia ser dividida em 2 perguntas, uma questionando como criar um drag-n-drop no HTML, fazendo uso de javascript e outra de como salvar dados de uma ordenação de componentes HTML no DOM, em uma base de dados.

Comment: Esse tutorial do Html5rocks pode te ajudar http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: Assim está bem melhor! Votei para reabrir, @LuizPicolo, dê uma olhada também.

Comment: Agora a pergunta está mais clara, tópico re-aberto.

Comment: Agora sim está com mais conteúdo. Retiro o meu -1

Answer (score 1):

Adocumentação do jQuery permite dois parametros na função drop, o segundo é o elemento arrastado, assim pode tentar:

```
function drop(ev, ui) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var texto = dropped.innerText; // dá-lhe o texto do elemento arrastado
    var coluna = $(dropped).index(); // dá-lhe o numero da coluna a começar em zero
    var linha = $(dropped).closest('tr').index(); // dá-lhe o numero da linhaa começar em zero
```

E assim, tendo o index da linha/coluna pode ir buscar o seu `text()` com

```
var textoColuna = $('table tr:first td:eq(' + coluna + ')').text();
var textoLinha = $('table tr:eq(' + linha + ') td:first').text();
```

Aliás, dentro da função `drop()` o `this` refere-se ao elemento destino, assim pode usar-se:

```
var coluna = $(this).index(); 
var linha = $(this).closest('tr').index();
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/WbLG8/)

Comment: +1 foi a mesma coisa que eu pensei, agora é só pegar o textContent dos elementos representado pela coluna e linha, e ele vai ter a informação desejada.

Comment: Ola Gabriel obrigado pelo conhecimento.

Comment: @GabrielGartz Gabriel obrigado pelo conhecimento. Essa maneira que tu fez é um pouco diferente da minha né, estou usando a função do html5, essa é com jquery | droppable |? essa que você mandou resolveu o problema. Sabe se tem como resolver o problema com o codigo acima? exemplo que coloquei acima. Tem como colocar var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var texto = dropped.innerText; 
    var coluna = $(dropped).index(); 
    var linha = $(dropped).closest('tr').index();  <br /> dentro do meu exemplo.                 Ou estou totalmente equivado

Comment: @user4870, pode colocar o seu codigo no exemplo que eu dei? Assim é mais fácil poder ajudar. Mude o meu código, carregue em "update" e coloque o link aqui.

Comment: @Sergio brigado por sua ajuda esta sendo bastante útil.

Comment: @Sergio  meu código esta acima. Posso mandar meu sistema compactado em seu email?

Comment: @Kleber, o melhor é colocar aqui, num jsfiddle, para todos poderem ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Sergio o problema foi resolvido com uma biblioteca otima chamada REDIPS_drag segue o link com o download e exemplos para quem precisar.  http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/